# Azure blob storage client in java intellij not initializing

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, initialization, blob, noclassdeffounderror

Running into an error while initializing context for an azure blob container storage..
Would greatly appreciate any help

```
>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [listeners.AzureBackupManagerContextListener]
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

[....]

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector$XmlExtensions
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        ... 76 more
```

Comment: Do you use "Azure Toolkit" plugin?

Comment: I do now, not sure if I was then.. definately needed I would say !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also hit this issue and was able to solve this with adding fasterxml jackson dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah I did this, works now.. another thing I ran into was versioning
```xml
    <properties>
        <jackson.version>2.13.2</jackson.version>
    </properties>


        <dependency> <!-- needed for blob -->
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: im sorry I cannot get the syntax for multiline xml code to work in a comment.. 
Basically you have <properties> set a version</properties>
and you refer to that later in <version>${jackson.version}</version>